# How do I install CM11 on YU Yuphoria?

Tags: cyanogenmod, downgrade, micromax-yu-yuphoria

I have recently bought YU yuphoria which came with CyanogenOS 12 . But I am having so many issues with Android Lollipop like many other users.

Now, I want to install CM11 which is working great on my friend's YU Yureka. I have downgraded YU Yureka from CM12 to CM11 by following [this link](http://webtrickz.com/how-to-downgrade-yureka-from-cm12-lollipop-to-cm11-kitkat/).

Can I do the same with the YU Yuphoria?

Comment: "I am having so many issues with Android lollipop like many other users" what issues? Who else is having this issues?

Comment: calling app is taking time to lauch, heating problem. IMHO, Kitkat is better than lollipop.

Comment: As far as I've seen the news, this phone of yours was (when launched) came with CyanogenOS 12 (Lollipop), so it is very unlikely that a KikKat build would be available. At least not a stock build because that would not make any sense for your OEM, and I wouldn't bet on custom ROMs either since people move forward usually. // May be you should find that ROM available for your device, and then possibly, someone else would provide a tutorial if you don't end up finding one, that is.